# Combine two texts into one in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a website. I have got the information I need but I can't figure out how to output the prod title followed by a space and then the amount and then keep doing down until the end.

```
g_data = soup.find_all("h4", {"class": "prod-title"})
p_data = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "amount"})

for item in g_data:
    print (item.text)
for item in p_data:
    print (item.text)

print ("g_data" + "p_data")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip()`.

```
for g, p in zip(g_data, p_data):
    print(g.text, p.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `zip()` function.

Usage:

```
for a, b in zip(g_data, p_data):
    print(a.text, b.text)
```

Documentation for zip - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0):

You can use izip function https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip which returns an iterator instead of the list

izipped = izip(iter1, iter2)

for x in izipped:
    print(str(x[0], str(x[1]))